# Multi sig solutions for validator withdrawal key

Tags: multisignature, eth-2.0, staking, validators

Validators for ETH2.0 have a pair of keys: 1 for validation (hot wallet) and another one for withdrawal (cold wallet). It looks like the tx data for depositing the stake requires both public keys for which I assume a Gnosis safe wouldn’t do for any of these keys. Is there any solution for using a multi sig wallet in the withdrawal side of the validator key pair?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a 1multi-signature (multisig) wallet1 for the withdrawal key, but it requires a bit of extra setup. One option is to use a smart contract-based `multisig wallet`, such as Gnosis Safe, that supports Ethereum 2.0 withdrawals. **However, currently, Gnosis Safe does not natively support Ethereum 2.0 withdrawals**.

To use a multisig wallet for the withdrawal key, you will need to deploy a custom smart contract that acts as a `proxy` between the validator and the cold wallet. This contract would hold the cold wallet `withdrawal key`, and the validator's multisig wallet would hold a share of the key.The contract would be programmed to require a certain number of multisig wallet owners to approve a withdrawal before the withdrawal key can be used to execute the withdrawal transaction.

Comment: But a multi-sig contract doesn’t have a public key for me to plug in the transaction data

Comment: How can a multisig hold part of a withdraw key? Won't that just be public information on chain that anyone could just steal?

Comment: @Bruce Yes you're right but In the case of an ETH2.0 validator withdrawal key, one approach to using a multi-sig wallet would be to use a smart contract that requires the approval of multiple parties to initiate a withdrawal transaction. Each party would hold their own private key outside of the blockchain, and would need to sign off on the transaction using their private key.